# WhatsApp away from Wi Fi?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, downloading

When I am away from WiFi, I do not want to receive nor send messages or media on WhatsApp.  Where on my Moto G can I make this setting?  Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way, on Whatsapp, to disable send/receive messages. When I want to save my internet, I just go to the phone's configuration and disable all internet conections (leaving just Wifi on, since it is "free") - but it would affect all apps.

The best you could do on Whatsapp is to not download media - go to Configuration -> Storage Data and disable all automatic media download.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to restrict background data usage for certain apps. Here, "data" or "mobile data" means the Internet connection you get through 4G or 3G, and not what you get through Wi-fi. (I don't know how to restrict foreground data usage for certain apps, so you would have to also avoid opening WhatsApp if you don't want it to use data.)

- Go to "Settings", "Connections", "Data usage".
- Tap "Mobile data usage"
- Scroll down and tap "WhatsApp", or whatever app you want to restrict
- Turn off "Allow background data usage"